# Launch ajax on launch modal window (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have modal window that opens via button click

Here is code in View:

```
<button style="margin-bottom: 20px;" class="btn  btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Описание вакансии</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" data-backdrop="false">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Описание</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Questions/Info.cshtml")
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here is code of modal:

```
  <div id="detail">

</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        emaillist_update2();
    });

    function emaillist_update2() {
        var url = window.location.pathname;
        var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        $.ajax({
            url:'@Url.Action("Displayinfo2","Questions")',
            type: 'Post',
            dataType: 'Json',
            data: {
                ID: id
            },
            success: function(result) {
                var info = result;

                $("#detail").append(info.Greeting);
            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Maodal is Partial View

My problem in that script in modal not work where it opens. Looks like it works when page loads, not modal.

How I can run it when I open modal?

Comment: Take the function call out of the document.ready and move it to the button onclick event. You'll need to handle the modal visibility in the function as well, or add some visibility logic in the onclick event.

Comment: This is because @Html.Partial is rendered on page load and not when the button is clicked.  Add this to the button will make it run the  function on each click: onClick=" emaillist_update2()"

Comment: @Logan Can you please upvote the answer below.  It worked for me.  Only calling script when model button clicked.  Upvote so others can view answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it:

Partial view in view shared named _Info.cshtml:

```
A Partial View
<div id="detail" />
```

Controller/Model:

```
public class MyDataModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

//Create an edmx to your table
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index2005(string ID)
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            Greeting = "This is a Greeting" 
        }
        , @"application/json");
    }

    public ActionResult Index2005(int? id) //argument to differ from post
    {
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index2005</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".btn").click(function () {
                emaillist_update2()
            })

            function emaillist_update2() {
                alert("ap");
                var url = window.location.pathname;
                //var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                var id = "you can compute the id";

                $.ajax({
                    //modified the url for my use
                    url: '/Home/Index2005',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { ID: id },
                    success: function (result) {
                        $("#detail").append(result.Greeting);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert('Error');
                    }
                });
            }

        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button style="margin-bottom: 20px;" class="btn  btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Описание вакансии</button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" data-backdrop="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Описание</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @*put partial class in views share*@
                    @Html.Partial("_Info")
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```